# Get date based on month, year, day and week number (ColdFusion)

Tags: date, coldfusion

I found a similar answer to my question, but it was in SQL and kinda went over my head ([Given year, month, day and week number how to find the date?(Sql Server 2005 Set based)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325939/given-year-month-day-and-week-number-how-to-find-the-datesql-server-2005-set)).

I'm writing a schedule creation app where a user will select the month, day of week (Sun-Sat, aka 1-7), and choose optionally if this will recur throughout the month each week.

Given that, I'm trying to write a function in ColdFusion that will return the actual date if I pass in the month, day, week number, and year.  Dates always confuse the heck out of me.

Comment: Your question confuses the heck out of me. You want to drop in the month, day, and year and get the date back?

Comment: @RobG, a sample of something you've already written/tried in ColdFusion would be ideal.

Comment: What would the day you pass in actually represent?

Comment: Are you basing this requirement off the Cron format?  Do you only require month/day/weekNum/Year?  If you have week number, do you require the month too?

Comment: By Day I mean DayOfWeek.  And by week I mean WeekNumber (typically 1-4 in most months).  Make sense?

Comment: Have you looked at cflib.org? Depending on what you are doing, you might be able to use something like [GetNthOccOfDayInMonth](http://www.cflib.org/udf/GetNthOccOfDayInMonth) function as a basis. It currently returns a day number, but you could easily adapt it to return a "date" or throw an error if the week number is invalid.  Just change the last if/else to either `throw` or `return CreateDate(TheYear,TheMonth,TheDayInMonth)`.  BUT a lot depends on your app and the "recurring" part of the task. Depending on the specifics, you might be better off doing this in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

So I know this is an old post but here are some current options in script or tag.

```
Week Number<br />
<cfscript>
    myDateTime = now();
    WriteOutput(week(myDateTime & "<br/>"));
</cfscript>
<br />

Day of week<br />
<cfscript>
    mydayofweek = (DayOfWeek(myDateTime));
    WriteOutput(DayOfWeek(myDateTime & "<br/>"));
</cfscript>
<br />

Day of year<br />
<cfscript>
    WriteOutput(DayOfYear(myDateTime & "<br/>"));
</cfscript>
<br />

Days in month<br />
<cfscript>
    WriteOutput(DaysInMonth(myDateTime & "<br/>"));
</cfscript>
<br />

<!--- What date are we working with --->
<cfset workingdt = '2022-5-05' />
<!--- Get the week start date. --->
<cfset dtWeekStart = (workingdt - DayOfWeek( workingdt ) + 1) />
<!--- Get the week end date. --->
<cfset dtWeekEnd = (workingdt + (7 - DayOfWeek( workingdt ))) />
<!--- Get the working week --->
<cfset dtworkingweek = '#week(workingdt)#' />


<br />
<!--- Output the dates: --->
<cfoutput>
Today: #DateFormat( workingdt )#<br />
Week Start: #DateFormat( dtWeekStart )#<br />
Week End: #DateFormat( dtWeekEnd )#<br />
Week Number: #dtworkingweek#<br />
</cfoutput>
<br />
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).