# Retrieve date from year, week number, day name in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Thanks for all for reading my questions, I have fallen a big problem to retrieve date from SQL Server 2012 by providing year, week number and day name.

Suppose I have

```
Year = 2016
Week number = 1
Day Name ='FRI'
First day of week='SUN'
```

Expected result:

```
01-01-2016
```

How can I do that?

EDIT: I have found similar solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325939/given-year-month-day-and-week-number-how-to-find-the-datesql-server-2005-set) but I have no month name.

Comment: If You have this data ( Year : 2016, WeekNo = 1, DayName = 'MON' ), what You expect to get - Error or 4-1-2016 ( dmy ) ?  And what day week begins - SUN or MON ?

Comment: @Shohel you are describing a mix between american week standard and iso week. Iso week starts on a monday, and can be part of 2 different years, thursday describes which year this week is part of. American standard starts on a sunday and the week will always end between years, meaning saturday 1/1 will be week 1 and sunday will be week 2. I strongly suggest you do not try to generate a new standard

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is based on the solution to the question in the link you provided.
Basically, I've created a calendar that holds the dates since January 1st of the year till @x weeks after that, and then queried that calendar:

```
-- provided data:
DECLARE @Year int = 2016,
        @WeekNumber int = 1,
        @DayName char(3) = 'Fri';

-- Calculate start date and end date
DECLARE @StartDate date, 
        @EndDate date;

SELECT  @StartDate = CAST('01-01-'+ CAST(@Year as char(4)) as date),
        @EndDate = DATEADD(WEEK, @WeekNumber, @StartDate)

-- Create the calendar
;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT @StartDate as TheDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, TheDate)
    FROM CTE 
    WHERE DATEADD(DAY, 1, TheDate) <= @EndDate
)

-- Finally, query the calendar:
SELECT  TheDate
FROM CTE
WHERE DATEPART(WEEK, TheDate) = @WeekNumber 
AND YEAR(TheDate) = @Year 
AND DATENAME(WEEKDAY, TheDate) LIKE @DayName + '%'
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

results:

```
TheDate
----------
2016-01-01
```

**Note:** This solution will return no rows if the day you specify is mon, since the first week of 2016 starts on Friday.

Comment: Needs `OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)` (or 366) - try it with Week > 14

Comment: @LesH: Thanks for the catch! fixed.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, very helpful your answer. I have updated my questions. just added first day of week.

Comment: @ZoharPeled No problem -  I was just about to post virtually exactly the same answer - you beat me to it :)

Comment: @Shohel about the first day of the week, [read this.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx)

Comment: @ZoharPeled, if the week start from Sunday, then what will be the week number of 01-01-2016. I think it can be 52th week of 2015. so if i set Year : 2016, WeekNo = 52, DayName = 'FRI' , output is 2016-12-23. this is not right.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, for all year I want to set first day of week sun. how can i do that.

Comment: I don't follow. the week start have no barring on the week day of a date. the 23rd of December 2016 will be Friday no matter what day starts the week.

Answer (score 1):

TRY THIS

```
   DECLARE @Year        varchar(4)
DECLARE @WeekDayday  varchar(10) 
DECLARE @WeekNumber  int        
SET @Year        ='2016'  
SET @WeekDayday  ='fri'   
SET @WeekNumber  =1


--used to solve
DECLARE @StartDate datetime
       ,@EndDate   datetime
       ,@FirstWeek int

SET @StartDate='01-01-'+' '+@Year
SET @EndDate=@StartDate+38
SET @FirstWeek=DATENAME(week,@StartDate)-1

;with AllDates AS
(
    SELECT @StartDate AS DateOf, DATENAME(week,@StartDate)-@FirstWeek AS WeekOf, DATENAME(weekday,@StartDate) AS WeekDayOf
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DateOf+1, DATENAME(week,DateOf+1)-@FirstWeek AS WeekOf, DATENAME(weekday,DateOf+1) AS WeekDayOf
        FROM AllDates
    WHERE DateOf<@EndDate
)
SELECT
    DateOf
    FROM AllDates
    WHERE WeekOf=@WeekNumber AND WeekDayOf LIKE @WeekDayday+'%'
    ORDER BY DateOf
```

Answer (score 0):

How about improve [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325939/given-year-month-day-and-week-number-how-to-find-the-datesql-server-2005-set) answer by evaluate month name by week number:

```
--given info
DECLARE @Year        varchar(4);
DECLARE @MonthName   varchar(10);
DECLARE @WeekDayday  varchar(10);
DECLARE @WeekNumber  int;

SET @Year        = '2016';
SET @WeekDayday  = 'Tue';  
set @WeekNumber  = 46;

-- get month number by week
declare @w int = 0;
declare @m int = 1;
while (@w <= @WeekNumber and @m < 13) begin
  set @w = datepart(wk, datefromparts(@year, @m, 1));
  if (@w <= @WeekNumber and @m < 13) begin
    set @m = @m + 1;
  end;
end;
set @m = @m -1;

-- get month name
set @MonthName = left(DateName(month ,DateAdd(month ,@m ,0 ) - 1), 3);


--used to solve
DECLARE @StartDate datetime
       ,@EndDate   datetime
       ,@FirstWeek int

SET @StartDate='01 '+@MonthName+' '+@Year
SET @EndDate=@StartDate+38
SET @FirstWeek=DATENAME(week,@StartDate)-1


;with AllDates AS
(
    SELECT @StartDate AS DateOf, DATENAME(week,@StartDate)-@FirstWeek AS WeekOf, DATENAME(weekday,@StartDate) AS WeekDayOf
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DateOf+1, DATENAME(week,DateOf+1)-@FirstWeek AS WeekOf, DATENAME(weekday,DateOf+1) AS WeekDayOf
        FROM AllDates
    WHERE DateOf<@EndDate
)
SELECT
    DateOf ,WeekOf ,WeekDayOf
    FROM AllDates
    WHERE datepart(wk, DateOf) = @WeekNumber AND WeekDayOf LIKE @WeekDayday+'%'
    ORDER BY DateOf
```